# Ocaml : multiply expression (*) int int -> int

Tags: expression, ocaml

Why Ocaml does not support `# (*) int int -> int` expression operation as `# (+) int int -> int`?

(i.e: `# (/) 81 9 -> 9`, `# (*) 9 9 -> Warning 1: this is the start of a comment.`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `(*` is the start of a comment in OCaml syntax:

```
(* hello, I'm a comment *)
```

The workaround is to add spaces:

```
( * ) 9 9
```

is the `*` operator.